# Emoji Fruit n Veg

Tags: rebus, emoji

[image]

Fruit n Veg Emojis I made earlier today! Easy 'peas'y ) Hope you've all been getting your 5 a day this Easter )

[ps: I used screenshot to ensure proper emoji rendering]

Comment: What's the easiest way to wikifi this?

Comment: I've created a community wiki with some answers already there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community Wiki (please add to this with the below format if you have an answer):

**Format:**

Clue No (@Name):

> Answer (Brief explanation)

---

1 (@Stiv):

> Zucchini (zoo+key+knee)

2 (@BeastlyGerbil):

> Eggplant (egg+plant)

3 (@DanielMathias):

> Cabbage (cab+age)

4 (@DanielMathias):

> Asparagus (asp+par+a+gas)

5 (@El-Guest):

> Lime (lie+me)

6 (@BeastlyGerbil):

> Pear (P+ear)

7 (@Stiv):

> Apricot (ape+rye+cot)

8 (@JMP):

> Mango (man+go)

9 (@BeastlyGerbil):

> Turnip (turn+eye+P)

10 (@BeastlyGerbil):

> Beetroot (bee+trout)

11 (@Stiv):

> Cauliflower (call+eye+flower)

12 (@El-Guest):

> Apple (Ape+pals)

13 (@El-Guest):

> Nectarine (neck+tar+rain)

14 (@El-Guest):

> Date (They’re on a date!)

15 (@BeastlyGerbil):

> Carrot (car+rat)

16 (@Stiv):

> Cherry (chair+rye)

17 (@JMP):

> Lemon (lie+man)

18 (@JMP):

> Kiwi (key+we)

19 (@jafe):

> Ginger (gin+jar)

20 (@BeastlyGerbil):

> Banana (bar+nana)

21 (@El-Guest):

> Chilli (chill+eye)

22 (@JMP):

> Dill (die+ill)

Comment: Thanks .. 2,6,9,10,15,20 all correct

Comment: @Omar can you check all of them now? I don’t think some of mine are correct, for example...

Comment: @Omar does mine look better for #5 and do we have them all now?

Comment: Yes it does ) there’s another answer to 14 ?

Comment: @Omar second try for #14?

Comment: Possibly rot13(bavba (havba))?

Comment: Date correct! Well played all 